# ein Date klarmachen

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following dialogue in the German TV series "How to Sell Drugs Online (Fast)":

- A: Was willst du denn machen?
- B: Dir ein Date klarmachen.

Context: A teenager A is talking to a girl online, but doesn't have the guts to meet her in real life. His friend B gets his cellphone in order to invite the girl to go out.

Does "ein Date klarmachen" mean "to get a date"? I don't see any similar meaning in https://www.wordreference.com/deen/klarmachen when the verb is transitive.

Comment: VtC because clearly answered by https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/klarmachen [4]

Comment: @Raketenolli I don't think it's obvious. Wenn dann ist es Synonyme [2].

Comment: [2] with the intention of [4] ;-)

Comment: @Raketenolli First, IMHO there is no seduction in this context, the subject of the sentence A is just helping his friend B get a date; the intention of seducing is in B towards the girl C and B is the indirect object of "klarmachen", so I disagree that the meaning [4] applies here. Second, the meaning [2] in Wiktionary is "to make something ready" and I don't know what "to make/get a date ready" should mean. In English, that would never be used as a synonym of "to get", "to arrange". Lastly, [2] is given as "sea language" and it's hard to figure out that it can be used in other contexts.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The meaning of "klarmachen" as "getting something (ready)" comes from the "sea language" -> getting the ship ready (to cast off)

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/klarmachen [4]: organisieren, [endgültig] **verabreden**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[klarmachen (wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klarmachen):

- Bedeutungen:

  > transitiv, umgangssprachlich:
  > [2] Fliegersprache, Seemannssprache: **bereit machen**
- Synonyme:

  > [2] **vorbereiten**

`Klarmachen` is definitely colloquial and is used in the sense of `"getting something for someone"` or `"make something possible for someone"`.

> A: Kannst du Gras **klarmachen**? (Can you get weed?)

> B: Klar! Was brauchst du? (Sure! What do you need?)

---

> Does "ein Date klarmachen" mean "to get a date"?

Yes. He wants to arrange a rendezvous for him.

Comment: I think "klarmachen" only means "to make something [the date] ready" here, and shall not be understood in the context of seducing. If B really meant to get the girl ready for sex, he would use other terms, such as "flachlegen".

Comment: @PMF: No, wait - if B were to "flachlegen" the lady, then it would be *B* getting intimate with her, but from the context as described in the question, he wants to help *A* getting closer to her.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's kind of true. I don't know how the sentence "Soll ich sie für dich flachlegen?" would be understood. Normally, you don't do that for someone else, especially since it kind of implies that it is against the will of the woman.

Comment: @PMF: Indeed, what a weird sentence. I'm pretty sure it cannot be understood in any other way than the asker planning to get intimate with her, which seems to drastically reduce the situations where that sentence could be applicable. I too sense the implication you describe, but I'm not sure whether it is directly an effect of the expression "jemanden flachlegen" (and, given that this can well be consensual, if somewhat rudely expressed, an overinterpretation at that).